# Can you use an anotation in an Spring Boot Entity to Bcrypt a password

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I started my internship and was told to update the user entity password field with a Bcrypt annotation, but I am not able to find any data on that subject.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to define the Bcrypt-Encoder in your application.

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder encoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}
```

Then you can inject the PasswordEncoder into your Service with the `@Autowired` annotation to hash raw passwords.

```
@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public User registerNewUser(User newUser, String rawPassword){
    newUser.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(rawPassword));
    // TODO persist new user to database
    return newUser;
}
```

Make sure to use this PasswordEncoder for password matching in your authentication process too.

The next more complex step would be to hash the passwords of existing users if there are any.

Here is a tutorial on Bcrypt in Spring:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-registration-password-encoding-bcrypt

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure I should do that in the Service?

Comment: Depends on your application structure. I would do the encoding on object creation which usually happens somewhere in the service-layer.